# Is it significant to perform Rudra Abhishekam?

Tags: mantras, shiva-lingam, rudraksha

What are the benefits of doing Rudra Abhishekam ?

Comment: Are you asking benefits of **Abhishekam**?

Comment: Personal advice questions are off-topic for this forum, please rephrase your question or it might be closed. [See here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/379/2995) for what are on-topic questions for hinduism.stackexchange.

Comment: I thinks this question is okay. Not look like a personal advice

Answer (score 3):

Sri Sri Ravi Shankar says it creates positive vibrations. He says the namakam part of it is bowing to the many names of the Lord. Chamakam is asking for blessings and manifesting that which is within. He says he does not know the actual meaning, but it was heard from the akasha when rishis were meditating. In my own experience, rudrabhishekham purifies negative deeds and words, and deepens meditation, creating a deeper respect and peace with nature. It is very auspicious. It connects you to the aspect of Shiva, who is the consciousness over the material universe.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Answer (score 3):

To add more details to the answer of Marcus, the *Rudrabhishekam* is done in two parts and the mantras have a positive effect on the mind:

> *Rudrabhiskek* is an ancient chanting which was downloaded from the *Akasha* (space). When the ancient sages sat in meditation, they heard these sounds (of the mantras), and they started transferring to other
>   people what they heard (and that is how the Rudrabhishek become known
>   to mankind).
>
> *The effect of Rudrabhishek is, it creates positive energy and removes negative vibrations.* The main thing is the vibration, that is it. If
>   you ask me, ’Do you know the meaning of all the chants? I will say, ’I
>   also don’t know.’ It’s the vibration of the chants that is more
>   important than the meaning. When Rudrabishek happens, nature
>   flourishes; nature becomes joyful and happy. Mainly, it creates more
>   positive vibrations; more so when people are meditating.

First Part of Rudrabhishekam

> There are two parts to *Rudrabhishekam*, the first part says, ’Namo,
>   namo, namo, namo’.
>   *Mana* means *mind*. The word mind in English comes from the Sanskrit word *Mana*. *Nama* is the reverse of the mind. *The mind going to its
>   source is called Nama.*
>
> When the mind goes outside to experience the world, it is *Mana*. When
>   the mind goes back to its source, it is *Nama*, and when it goes to
>   its source what does it find? It finds that *everything is made up of
>   one consciousness*.
>
> Today, scientist are talking about the *God Particle* – the one
>   particle by which everything has been made. Thousands of years ago the
>   Rishis said the same thing, that everything is made up of *one thing,*
>   and that they called *Brahman*.
>
> That which is neither male nor female, which is nothing but a Tattva
>   (Tattva means principle), by which everything is made, is called
>   *Bramhan*. And when that *Bramhan* becomes personal, it is called Shiva Tattva – the innocent divinity that is in everything. That is
>   why we say, ‘Namo, namo!’
>
> In the trees, in the greenery, in the birds, even in the thieves, and
>   in a dacoit, everywhere, it is the same *one* principle that present.

The Second Part of Rudrabhishekam

> Then, the second part will say, ‘Chame, chame, chame, chame.’ You have
>   heard this, isn’t it?! This means, *'Everything is in me'.* ‘Me’ in
>   English comes from the Sanskrit word *’Ma’*, which means 'Myself'. ‘Ma
>   Ma’ means ’ For Me’ and ‘In Me’. So, everything is in terms of
>   'Myself'.
>
> The second part is *'Everything is for me, and everything is in terms
>   of me.*
>
> Even for the numbers they say, ‘*Ekaachame*’, which means, one, two,
>   three, four, they are all my form.
>
> Like that, ‘*Sugamchame*’, happiness for me!
>
> ‘*Abhayanchame*’, fearlessness, happiness, health, all the good things
>   in the universe, let them all come to me, and they are all part of me.
>   That is it!
>
> As this is being chanted, usually milk and water runs through the
>   crystal, drop by drop. This is the ancient method. It is done with
>   water, or by putting herbs in fire.

Why is Rudrabhishekam Done on Monday?

> When done on Mondays it is even more special. Monday is the day of the
>   moon, and the moon and mind are connected. Mantra, mind, moon, they
>   are all connected somewhere. So in India, it is a tradition to have
>   this chanting in the Ashrams every Monday.
>
> All the five elements are used in pooja. Pooja means honoring all the
>   elements. So, fire, water, incense sticks, fruits, flowers, rice,
>   whatever nature has given to us, those things are used (for worship)
>   along with the chanting.
>
> Just doing it as a ritual is not that effective because it is said
>   that *the Veda Mantras are effective when people are awake from
>   within*; for them, these mantras have more meaning. So, these mantras
>   help you to go deep into meditation.

Excerpts from an article by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: 
https://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/17184919/.../understandingshiva.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This Abhishekham is for Lord Mahadeva. Shiva has eleven forms of [Rudras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudras). In this Pooja all the eleven Rudras are worshiped. After the aavahan (welcoming of the deity), sthaapna (giving seat to the deity) Laghu-nyasam is recited. Then Rudra Trishati is recited. Abhishekam is done to each of the 11 Rudras with all the 11 dravyas prescribed in the Shiv Puraana.

There are mainly three forms of Offernigs are related to Rudra Abhishekam .

> 1. Rudrabhishekam
> 2. Ekadash Rudrabhishekam and
> 3. Ekadasa Rudrabhishekam Homa

The Significance of this offering is to wash out his sins and to bring prosperity and happiness in his family. The best time to perform the pooja is the prodosham day of every month as it is one of the favourite days of Lord Shiva. Alternatively, Mondays could also be considered auspicious for the puja. The pooja is accompanied by [Chamakam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shri_Rudram_Chamakam) and Namakam recitals and could be performed at any Shiva temples.

Comment: You should cite sources for your statements about the benefits of Rudra Abhishekham.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spoon(uddarina) of water worship him as Shiva. If you have a blade of grass worsip him as Ganesh. If you have a flower worship him as Vishnu, if you have kunkum, worship him as mother goddess, if you have a minute time, worship him as bramha.

Water is known to pure the self. This is the reason why it is taken at sankalpam time of puja and prokshana with mantra powered water to purify the surroundings. There is practice of taking bath/drinking water to get rid of eveil thoughts and to purify the self.

Sanathana dharma teaches the most simple and efficient ways to worship God with what one have according to his social & economical status. Persons according to their economical status may use golden/silver/copper or mud articles to worship God but the result depend on the concentration and their affection towards god.

Comment: You should cite sources.